# Derivative of AX'B with respect to X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Since $\frac{\partial \left( AXB \right)}{\partial X}={{B}^{T}}\otimes A$,
What is $\frac{\partial \left( A{{X}^{T}}B \right)}{\partial X}$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial(a_{ij}x_{jk}b_{k\ell})}{\partial x_{rs}}=a_{ir}b_{s\ell}$ while $\displaystyle\frac{\partial(a_{ij}x_{kj}b_{k\ell})}{\partial x_{rs}}=a_{is}b_{r\ell}$. I don't see how to express that particular swap of indices in notation with the $\otimes$ symbol.

Comment: @runway44 I guess you should multiply your first formula  by $\delta_{jr}\delta_{ks}$ and the second one accordingly.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Well $\partial x_{jk}/\partial x_{rs}=\delta_{jr}\delta_{ks}$. The formulas I wrote are the *result* of substituting with $\delta$s and simplifying.

Comment: @runway44 $\partial (a_{12}x_{23}a_{34})/\partial x_{11}=a_{11}b_{14}$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Sorry, didn't use superscripts because lazy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: @runway44 Ok, summations are included but not visible.

Comment: Let $F=(AX^TB),\,$ then utilize @runway44's comment to write the componentwise derivative without using any summations (visible or invisible)
$$\large{\frac{\partial f_{ij}}{\partial x_{kl}} = a_{il}b_{kj}}$$